# INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE when restoring from AVD cache for CI/CD pipeline instrumented tests

Tags: android, github-actions, android-virtual-device, instrumented-test

I'm trying to make a github actions workflow to run instrumented tests on Android.

My file has steps similar to:

- actions/checkout@v3
- actions/setup-java@v3
- gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
- actions/cache@v3
- if: steps.avd-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true' -> reactivecircus/android-emulator-runner@v2 (generate AVD snapshot)
- ./gradlew connectedCheck

I've found that whenever I'm restoring a AVD cache which was found (having the same key), then I get an error when trying to build and run the instrumented test.

```
Exception thrown during onBeforeAll invocation of plugin com.google.testing.platform.plugin.android.AndroidDevicePlugin.
Failed to install APK(s):
INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package "" signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!
```

This step passes when the AVD cache is not set and it's generating a new one. But re-using an AVD cache fails this step (`./gradlew connectedCheck`)

I'm not sure what to do here. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like a recent issue https://github.com/ReactiveCircus/android-emulator-runner/issues/319.

Comment: I've fixed this by downgrading to `reactivecircus/android-emulator-runner@v2.25.0`.